# How to adjust the Yii2 listview row spacing

Tags: listview, yii2, spacing

I have a list view in my web page like

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary'=>false,
    'itemView' => '_listing'
]);?>
```

And my list item is

```
<li>
   <div class="well ad-listing clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 grid-style no-padding">
         <!-- Image Box -->
         <div class="img-box">
            <img src="<?=Yii::getAlias('@web/frontend/web/')?>uploads/<?=$boatModel->getThumbnail($model->pictures)?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            <div class="total-images"><strong><?=$boatModel->getPictureCount($model->pictures)?></strong> photos </div>
         </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
         <!-- Ad Content-->
         <div class="row">
            <div class="content-area">
               <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- Category Title -->
                  <div class="category-title"> <small><b><?=$model->mainCategory->category_english?> / <?=$model->category->category_english?></b></small> </div>
                  <div class="category-title"> <small><b><?= date("jS F, Y", strtotime($model->date)); ?></b></small> </div>
                  <!-- Ad Title -->
                  <h3><?=yii\helpers\Html::a($model->title, ['community/view', 'id' => $model->id]) ;?></h3>
                  <!-- Info Icons -->

                  <!-- Ad Meta Info -->
                  <ul class="ad-meta-info">
                     <li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><a href="#"><?=$model->address?></a> </li>

                  </ul>
                  <!-- Ad Description-->
                  <div class="ad-details">

                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                  <!-- Ad Stats -->
                  <br>
                  <!-- Price -->
                  <div class="price"> <span></span> </div>

                  <span><a href="#fav"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span>
                  <span><a href="#fav"><i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i></a></span>
                  <!-- Ad View Button -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Ad Content End -->
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

And my output is like [please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp3R3.jpg)

And i want to remove the space between the list view items.How can do that.i cant find that property in by inspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="well ad-listing clearfix" style="margin-bottom:5px">
```

Add style margin-bottom in list item page
or edit in css